# Unable to access the Tomcat default page from browser for EC2 using Public DNS or Elastic IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I have setup an `EC2` instance at `AWS` and I have `Java` and `Tomcat 9` installed on the `EC2` instance `Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS (HVM)`. I am able to connect to my EC2 instance using `SSH`(elastic IP)[`ssh -i "path/to/.pem-file" ubuntu@XX.XX.XX.XX`] but unable to access the Tomcat default page from a browser outside `EC2` using AWS `Public DNS address` or `Elastic IP`.

[image: EC2 INSTANCE]

I have added a Security Group and set up an inbound rule as below.

[image: Custom AWS Security Group]

This is the output of `iptables -nL` on `EC2`.

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8080

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I have gone through simlar posts here and followed the same steps mentioned on this
[article](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/11/set-up-an-amazon-ec2-instance-with-tomcat-and-mysql-5-minutes-tutorial/) but still
`http://ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com` does not load the Tomcat default page.

Need some help.

**Edit:**

```
netstat -na | grep 80
```

displays

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8080    :::*    LISTEN
```

suggests it is listening to only for IPv6 addresses and as per official docs, it [does not support Elastic IP addresses for IPv6](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/using-instance-addressing.html#ip-addressing-eips)

Comment: Well, one thing to note here: you have opened port 8080 inbound, but you're trying to access port 80. There are two things you could do: 1. try appending 8080 to the URL, like this: `http://ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080`, or  2. you can add port 80 to the list of inbound rules and try with the URL you are using now, i.e. `http://ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com`.

Comment: I flushed everything again. I tried `iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`, `iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT` and then `iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080` but 
none of `http://ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080` or `http://ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:80` loads anything.

Comment: You have to add ports to the list of *inbound rules*, not iptables. If the ports are not open in a Security Group, iptables won't help much.

Comment: Thank you Marko. I just now added. Now I have both 80 and 8080 open under Inbound rules at `EC2 Security Groups` under Source `0.0.0.0/0`. Still the same.

Comment: Well, one last question: is the Tomcat server actually running and listening on specified ports?

Comment: I think yes. I restarted Tomcat service as well. service `netstat -na | grep 80` gives `tcp6  0   0 :::8080  :::*  LISTEN` output on EC2.

Comment: It seems that it's listening only on an IPv6 address. Is that something you expect?

Comment: Hey, good point. It should be using IPv4 and not IPv6.

Comment: How to correctly set it up and where to configure?

Comment: You can explicitly set the `address` of the `<Connector>` to be the address of the IPv4 network interface.